# Error with Promises in NodeJs

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

i´m triying yo learn to use promises to make validations of mysql. This is my code.

```js
//main.js
var valida=   require('./modulos/validaciones');


var valor=valida.userP(data).then((rows,error)=>{
 console.log(rows);
});
console.log(valor);


//valida.js
var mysql=          require('mysql');

exports.userP= (data)=>{
 return promise = new Promise(resolve,reject)=>{
  conection.query(data.valida_user,(error,rows)=>{
   if (error) reject(error);
   console.log("Entra en validacion");
   console.log(rows);
   resolve(rows);
  });
 };
};
```

But when i run the code, console show me this `return promise = _new_ Promise(resolve,reject)=>{
SyntaxError: Unexpected token new`

I am using nodejs 8.11

Answer (score 2):

Change your code to this:

```
exports.userP = (data) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        conection.query(data.valida_user, (error, rows) => {
            if (error) return reject(error);
            console.log("Entra en validacion");
            console.log(rows);
            resolve(rows);
        });
    });
};
```

There were multiple mistakes:

1. The variable `promise` is not defined anywhere and is not needed.  You can just return the promise directly.
2. You were missing parens around `(resolve, reject)` to make it a proper arrow function declaration with multiple arguments.
3. You need a `return` before your `reject()` so processing will not continue.
4. You were missing a closing paren to close the `new Promise()`.

Comment: it throw me the same error `return new Promise(resolve,reject)=>{
               ^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token new`

Comment: @EleazarOrtega - Please look at the code in my answer because the error you show is NOT the code in my answer.  I did make some edits after first posting as I recognized more errors that needed fixing.

Comment: Wow, i´m sorry, i didnt read all... But you´re right... now my code run, but dont show de console.log inside the function of query...

Comment: Just return an object=pending

Comment: @EleazarOrtega - Yes, that's what returning a promise does.  You use `moduleName.userP(someData).then(result => { /* code here to use the result */})` to access the data.  You get data out of a promise with `.then()` or with `await`.

Comment: Strictly speaking, the third change is not required.  Calling `resolve()` after `reject()` has already been called (or vice-versa) has no effect.  It may be _clearer_ to have the explicit `return`, but not having it shouldn't cause anything worse than some spurious log messages in this case.

Comment: @aroth - Yeah, but come on.  It's clearly wrong to be logging things you don't intend to be called and very misleading too.  If you're done executing code, return.  Just because you can get away with it doesn't mean you should.

Answer (score 1):

This sould do the trick, basically this line:

```
return promise = new Promise(resolve,reject)=>{
```

For this:

```
return new Promise ((resolve,reject) => {
```

Full code below:

```js
//main.js
var valida=   require('./modulos/validaciones');


var valor=valida.userP(data).then((rows,error)=>{
 console.log(rows);
});
console.log(valor);


//valida.js
var mysql=          require('mysql');

exports.userP= (data)=>{
 return new Promise ((resolve,reject) => {
  conection.query(data.valida_user,(error,rows)=>{
   if (error) reject(error);
   console.log("Entra en validacion");
   console.log(rows);
   resolve(rows);
  });
 });
};
```

Comment: Same error `return new Promise(resolve,reject)=>{`
`SyntaxError: Unexpected token new`

Comment: Please read my full awnser , you need the double parentheses after the "new Promise"